# App hangs while acquiring in-app product purchases

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp

I'm developing a UWP app which has a single in-app purchase.

I've created in my Microsoft Developer account the in-app purchase and submitted it for review, which has been published in the Windows Store.

I've created the logic inside my app as follow:

```
    private async Task CheckInAppPremium()
    {
        #if DEBUG
        var file =
            await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Data\in-app.xml");
        await CurrentAppSimulator.ReloadSimulatorAsync(file);
        var licenseInformation = CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation;
        #else
        var licenseInformation = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;
        #endif
        if (!licenseInformation.ProductLicenses["Premium"].IsActive)
        {
            #if DEBUG
            var results = await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("Premium");
            #else
            var results = await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("Premium");
            #endif
            Success = results.Status == ProductPurchaseStatus.Succeeded;
            if (Success)
            {
                _localSettings.Values["premium"] = true;
                Messenger.Default.Send(new PremiumInAppAcquiredMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine when app is running in DEBUG mode, but when the app is compiled in Release, the app hangs at this line:

var licenseInformation = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;

I don't know what I missed, though I followed the Microsoft recommandations.

Comment: Have you associated app with your microsoft store account and added your ProductPurchaseId i.e. premium in your store account? Its stopping at `var licenseInformation = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;` as its trying to retrieve the value from your store account.

Comment: Yes my app is associated to the same account with which I've created the Premium in-app product. My app had already been published to the store, and submitted it again didn't solve the issue

Comment: So does your app work or is it crashing. The hang is attributed to LicenseInformation being retrieved synchronously.

Comment: The app works fine. The call to LicenceInformation hangs for 10 seconds then throw an Exception (I don't remember the type right now)